# People on an other network can't connect to my WAMP server

Tags: html, apache, http, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to host a WAMP server (WAMP version 3.0.6 on windows 10) and `http:'//localhost`, my internal IP and external IP (I  forwarded port 80) are working. I Also registered a free .tk domain that's working on my network. But on other WiFi networks people can't connect to my server using my external IP or my domain.

I tested it on my smartphone (using mobile data to simulate the other WiFi network) and I got the error `[My server's IP] took too long to respond`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you check your error.log file and see if there's a logged GET request?

Comment: Does it work when you use the `.tk` domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have to make sure that the router is firstly directing to your server machine(local IPs generally have the form 192.168.x.x) and to the correct port ,so if WAMP's Apache is running on port 80 router must redirect to your machine's 80 port.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it.
I double checked my port forwarding settings and changed the external IP from port 80. Then I saw a text: "When the External IP address is 0.0.0.0 you can access this port forwarding on internet, if you set a specific External IP address here the access is limited to only this IP address on internet", so I changed my external IP to 0.0.0.0 and now it's working!